# Passing dynamic values for ConditionalOperators when Aggregating in Spring Mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm new to mongo aggregation and I want to check whether following is possible in spring mongo. I'm aware we can write conditions as given,

```
ConditionalOperators.Cond cond = when(Criteria.where("status").is("PRESENT")).then(1)
                .otherwise(when(Criteria.where("status").is("ABSENT")).then(2)
                .otherwise(100));
```

Given that I have map with possible condition values, I want to know whether it is possible to pass the values using the map to the condition.

```
Map<String, Integer> dynamicValues = new HashMap<>();
dynamicValues.put("PRESENT", 1);
dynamicValues.put("ABSENT", 2);
```

This is what I have as of now. But it is not working as expected.

```
List<String> dynamicValues = Arrays.asList("PRESENT", "ABSENT");

ConditionalOperators.Cond.OtherwiseBuilder operator =  ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("status").is(dynamicValues.get(0))).then(0));

        for (String s : dynamicValues) {
            ConditionalOperators.Cond.OtherwiseBuilder shippingDestination = when(Criteria.where("status").is(s)).then(1);
            operator.otherwise(shippingDestination);
        }

        return (ConditionalOperators.Cond) operator;
```

I have hard coded the then value temporary.

Comment: Can you please provide the complete query?

Comment: @Valijon, I have added the current implementation in the code. But unfortunately it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to add the conditions dynamically without hardcoding the values using the following code snippet. Posting it so that it would be useful to someone else. Let me know if there is a better way to do this.

```
 private ConditionalOperators.Cond buildCondition() {
    List<String> elements = Arrays.asList("ABSENT", "PRESENT");
    ConditionalOperators.Cond previousCondition = null;
    ConditionalOperators.Cond resultCondition = null;

    //#### Conditions cannot be built without the otherwise condition, therefore, build conditions in reverse.
    ListIterator<String> listIterator = elements.listIterator(elements.size());

    while (listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
        ConditionalOperators.Cond currentCondition;
        boolean isLastElement = !listIterator.hasNext();
        String currentElement = listIterator.previous();
        // create the otherwise condition with the dynamic destination and priority.
        ConditionalOperators.Cond.OtherwiseBuilder otherWiseCondition = when(Criteria.where("status")
                .is(currentElement))
                .then(<add the real value>);

        if (isLastElement) {
            // if last element, add the else condition.
            currentCondition = otherWiseCondition.otherwise(<else condition value>);
        } else {
            //add the previous element as the otherwise condition.
            currentCondition = otherWiseCondition.otherwise(previousCondition);
        }

        resultCondition = currentCondition;
        previousCondition = currentCondition;
    }

    return resultCondition;
}
```